# How to get sentiment score of each aspect in a sentence

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I am new to NLP. I want to perform sentiment analysis of a product review.

**Input Text**: All the appetizers and salads were fabulous, the steak was horrible and the pasta was delicious!!!

**Output**:

ASPECT    ---------------- POLARITY ---------------------  SENTIMENT SCORE

appetizers ---------------- positive -----------------------------------+0.6

salads ----------------------positive ----------------------------------    +0.6

steak -----------------------negative ----------------------------------    -0.3

pasta ----------------------    positive -----------------------------------    +0.9

Is there any related library/tool/code to get the following. Here I would like to mention that I went through with this article [http://saujanyareddy.github.io/]. But, this does not give the Sentiment scores for each Aspect identified from a sentence.

Thanks.